# Call Javascript in Commandbutton

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am not all that familiar with JavaScript.  I have a piece of code below that was developed by a predecessor of mine for a Detail page button.  The code works fine, but I would now like to use it as part of an embedded Visualforce page's Commandbutton.  Can anyone help on how I would convert this to use in a script call for a VF page?

**Javascript (Detail Button):**

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")}
var a = new sforce.SObject("Account");
a.id = "{!Account.Id}";
a.Mark_Account__c = !{!Account.Mark_Account__c};
sforce.connection.update([a]);
window.location.reload();
```

**Javascript (VF Page):**

```
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Mark();
        {
            var a = new sforce.SObject("Account");
            a.id = "{!Account.Id}";
            a.Mark_Account__c = !{!Account.Mark_Account__c};
            sforce.connection.update([a]);
            window.location.reload();
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Mark" onClick="Mark();return false;"/>
    </apex:form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by scrip call for a VF page?

Comment: @Himanshu - I revised my code above to show what works for my Detail page button and what is not working for my VF page commandbutton.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

When you are on detail page of your record it will work in following way

```
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Mark();
        {
            var a = new sforce.SObject("Account");
            a.id = '{!Account.Id}';
            //var marked ='{!Account.Mark_Account__c}';
            a.Mark_Account__c=false;
            alert(a.Mark_Account__c);
            sforce.connection.update([a]);
            window.location.reload();
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Mark" onClick="Mark();return false;"/>
    </apex:form>
```

Comment: Thanks, however, when I click the button it does not update the checkbox field (Mark_Account__c).

Comment: alert(marked); to check the value

Comment: Where would I see the value to check it from the alert?

Comment: you can add that like after var marked ='{!Account.Mark_Account__c}';

Comment: OK.  I added that and checked the Console and it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: Mark is not defined".

Comment: check the updated answer.

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: this is function Mark() not function Mark();

Comment: I removed the semi-colon from the Mark() line and now I get the Alert box with the correct value, however, the value does not change in my record.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34568/discussion-between-himanshu-and-j-neilan).